# Selenium catch HTML every time change has been made in browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use Selenium so that my code and browser will be integrated - I want to get updated HTML page every time I made any change on the web page in the browser?

In other words I would like to run my app which would automatically start a browser and every time I do any change on the web page selenium automatically get changed HTML in java/python code. For example select a dropdown item might be a good example.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: @JeffC, thank you. I have update my question.

Comment: Where will you compare elements?

Comment: So you want to use one app to drive changes in the browser and have selenium report the changes? I'm still not sure what you are asking. Please give us a clear example of actions you are trying to track.

Comment: @JeffC, I want just one app which could report whatever HTML has changed in browser.